# I installed heroku toolbelt yesterday to deploy a django 1.7 app and everything worked fine but this morning its giving me the following error

Tags: linux

> bash: /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No
>   such file or directory

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 I have been stuck on
this issue for hours combing stack overflow and blogs for the answer
any help or suggestions please are so appreciated

Comment: but you didn't bother to tell us what you have tried to diagnose the problem. What is the result of `ls -l /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku;file /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku`, `ls -l /usr/bin/env; file /usr/bin/env` for starters. Do the outputs make sense? Are you upgrading existing versions or is this meant to be a clean install? Are you working on a system that has been working OK, and just this problem is an issue, or are you working in a VM, or ?? This sort of installation problem is usually better resolved on the S.E. related site `http://askubuntu.com`. ...

Comment: Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: it's been working fine for three months now this just start showing up,

Comment: but any way thanks for helping out